# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Error

Tags: technical-issues, blade-and-soul

Whenever I try to launch Blade & Soul through the launcher I get a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Error.

It says:

```
Runtime Error!

Program: C:\Program Files (x86)\NCSOFT\BnS\bin\Client.exe

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

[image: Error box screenshot]

I already reinstalled BnS 2 times, I have no Razer software running, I tried running `Enable3GBMem_Vista_Win7_32bit.bat` and running the launcher in compatiblity mode as well as reinstalling all Visual C++ packs.

I checked online but couldn't find anything.
Has anyone experienced this issue? Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried running as administrator? Also, try installing all pending windows updates and retry.

Comment: I'm running the latest version of Windows and I tried running it as administrator and it gave me the exact same error.